# Online story from early 2010s. A professional "griefer" is reformed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story online in the early 2010s.  It's told in first-person by a person who is a professional griefer/troll - someone who attempts to disrupt society in a variety of ways, generally in a mean-spirited way.  He doesn't feel particularly bad about it, but as the story starts, he's been captured (as part of some general societal process that has identified a lot of people who are like him), and is in a facility that attempts to reform him.  Initially, he plays along with the process, faking an interest in learning different skills and hoping to go back to his old ways for his own enjoyment even if he gets nothing out of it, but gradually, he becomes more sincere.  I think the term "griefer" was specifically used.  The story was novelette in length I think.  It was in an online source that portrayed it as science fiction - since it takes place in a future setting following a major societal upheaval.  I don't recall any particular future technology, though.

Comment: Reforming trolls certainly _seems_ like SF these days...

Comment: Just to clear one off, he isn't forced to play a troll in a virtual reality game, is he?

Comment: Not as I recall.  He called himself a grief error (as I recall) but he worked in the real world

Comment: Not "grief error" obviously - griefer